# Windows firewall is blocking file sharing and ping

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, windows-11

I am having trouble setting up file sharing on my Windows 11 PC. I have tried to set up the PC using the Network and Sharing Center (Network discovery is on, file and printer sharing is on). I have traced the problem to the firewall (I can access the folder and ping only if the firewall is off). All "File and Printer Sharing" rules are enabled.

Comment: Make sure wireless connections are set up as Private Networks.  Otherwise, did you mess with the Registry?   The settings you note plus Private Wireless connection allow my Windows 11 Pro systems to share date effortlessly. Firewall ON and set to Default.

Comment: My network is an ethernet connection, but I set it to private and have the same issue.

Comment: Are the rules for the correct profile enabled? (If you're looking through `wf.msc`, there might be public, private, and "domain" rules.) Are there any "Deny" rules set up? (Those have priority over any "Allow" rule.)

Answer (score 0):

Your network type is probably set to public (which is the default in the case of Wi-Fi). If the network type is public Windows will not allow incoming file and printer sharing connections.

Use this to change your network type to private and if it doesn't work just remove and re-add it -
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-a-wi-fi-network-public-or-private-in-windows-0460117d-8d3e-a7ac-f003-7a0da607448d

Please mind that even when the network type is set to private, Windows only allow connections from the local subnet. If you wish to allow connections from outside the local network you will need to edit the appropriate firewall rules. Obviously, it is not recommended to allow incoming connections to the file and printer sharing service from the Internet.

Comment: My network is an ethernet connection, but I set it to private and have the same issue. I can access the computer via Remote Desktop on other machines on the local network.

Comment: Something has gone wrong with your operating system. I left a full answer post for you (1) Reset firewall , (2) Repair install, and (3) reinstall windows if the damage is severe enough.

Answer (score 0):

> The settings you note plus Private Wireless connection allow my
> Windows 11 Pro systems to share date effortlessly. Firewall ON and set
> to Default.
>
> I always suggest private networking, but uou says "My network is an
> Ethernet connection, but I set it to private and have the same issue"

**(1)** Reset the Firewall to Default.  Windows 11 Defender security center, Firewall, near the bottom, "Reset Firewall to Default"

**(2)** Run TCP/IP Reset to ensure networking is good.

```
Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
```

**(3)** Now restart and reset Network Discovery and F&P Sharing. Make sure Password Protected Sharing is ON.

Test all this.

If this fails:

**First run a Windows 11 Repair Install**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will save an app. Run it, and create a USB Windows Installation key, then run Setup on the USB Key.

Let this run and Keep Everything.

After all is complete, test and see if file sharing is working.
.

**Second**,if all the above fails, then there is more serious Windows OS damage or a damaged Windows User Profile. Back up all your data  and email (check this), then run Windows 11 Reset (System, Update, Recovery).  This will reinstall Windows 11 and you will need to install your apps and recover your data and email.

Comment: I'm flabbergasted, but even a clean install of windows is exhibiting the same symptoms.

Comment: I do not know what is wrong with your systems, but I share folders/ files with Window 11  with ease.

Comment: I suggest you get or borrow a simple router and set it up (just vanilla) and try that